# Xcode Schema symbol with Swift Package Manage (SPM)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I recently upgraded to Xcode 12 and noticed that when I open a Swift Package for development I get a "target" symbol instead of a "building" symbol as my schema now.

What does the target mean?

[image]